# Como pegar o "id" de um input atraves de um this por parametro em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um input da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="pegarId(this)" id="custo_veiculo">
```

na minha função

```
function pegarId(id){
var = id????
}
```

de que forma eu conseguiria acessar esse id via `this` do meu input dentro da minha funcao e colocar em uma variável ?

Comment: this é uma referência de um objeto para ele mesmo. Tu tens que ter a propriedade definida na classe.

Answer (score 1):

O `this` é algo exclusivo de uma classe do javascript, mas você consegue pegar um `id` de um evento passando o evento na funçao. No seu caso seu evento é `onkeyup`, o evento você passaria na funçao `pegarId`, sendo assim:

```
onkeyup="pegarId(event)"
```

Depois na funçao `pegarId` você pega o id do evento `event.target.id`.

Se você executar esse codigo ai embaixo você vai receber o id do botao sempre que clicar nele e o id do input sempre que mudar algo dentro do imput e der enter.

```js
function pegarId(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<span>Exemplo 1: </span><input type="text" onchange="pegarId(event)" id="custo_veiculo" placeholder="escreve algo aqui e dê enter">
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="pegarId(event)" id="botao_feio">Exemplo 2</button>
```

Comment: Não use as publicações para pedir votos ou aceitação. Mantenha o foco no conteúdo técnico.

Comment: To pedindo voto nao meu consagrado, o problema é que, principalmente aqui no stack em portugues, o pessoal nao sabe usar o site e nao marca como certo as perguntas nunca. Se minha pergunta nao ajuda tem problema nenhum nao dar upvote, dar downvote ou nao marcar como correta.